# Check session from a view in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates, session, scope

What is the best way to check session from a view in CodeIgniter, it shows no way in their user guide, otherwise I will have to make two views on everything, which is kinda weird...still a newbie to CodeIgniter...

Please Help! Thanks...

Comment: +1, I'm new to CI / MVC in general and had this exact same question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Load it into the view like any other piece of data...

```
$data['item'] = $this->session->userdata('item');
$this->load->view('view', $data);
```

Answer (score 8):

In view, you can access all loaded library, model, and helper function directly. If in controller you have load the session, or do it in autoload, then doing this in views will work:

```
<?php echo $this->session->userdata('session_key'); ?>
```

If you want to access some function that haven't loaded in autoload or in the controller, you can use this:

```
<?php
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->load->model('some_model');
echo $CI->some_model->some_function($some_param);
?>
```

I usually use this for a common view that loaded by other views, such as displaying visitor country flag, etc.

Hope this help.