# SESSION missing from view

Tags: php, codeigniter

as per title above, when I trigger the controller with a hyperlink, it does runs the controller function but I couldn't get the value of SESSION after redirect from controller. The code is as follows...

```
function langpref($lang){       
    $this->load->helper('url');
    redirect(ABSOLUTE_PATH, 'location');        

    $this->session->set_userdata('cur_lang', 'xxx');        
}
```

*Note: ABSOLUTE_PATH is a constant of the hyperlink, and I already load the SESSION library in the autoload file.

In my view file, I written the code as follows...

```
<?php echo $this->session->userdata('cur_lang');?>
```

and it doesn't print out the SESSION value.

Comment: a rare chance to miss, but have you enabled session library in your codeigniter by putting its info in config.php? Secondly, I wouldn't recommend you using codeigniter sessions, as it stores all data in cookies, which can be viewed openly using javascript (if mcrypt not enabled). And if this cookies as copied as it is to other browsers those same session would be operable from other browsers or computers too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check session from a view in CodeIgniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733149/check-session-from-a-view-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Approach:** You cannot access session variables like that

```
<?php $ci =& get_instance(); ?>
<div>
   <?php echo $ci->session->userdata('cur_lang') ?>
</div>
```

**Second Approach:** Another way you can do this is pass the session data to the view

On your controller

```
$data['userdata'] = $this->session->userdata;
$this->load->view('your/view', $data);
```

On your view

```
echo $userdata['cur_lang'];
```

Comment: still it's not working bro, any other way to call out the session?

Comment: @KYSH, Both the methods works perfectly. Check the update and check you code again. If you still can't run it post the codes on your question.

Comment: alright, its working now Starx, thanks for your help and its my fault that I should set it first before I redirect, ERROR DETECTED!

Comment: @Starx: "You cannot access session variables like that" is not true. `$this` works perfectly fine in a view, it's still in the context of the current controller/method.

Comment: @Madmartiganm , I am not sure about that. Anyways, I just found out another question exactly [same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733149/check-session-from-a-view-in-codeigniter)

Comment: @Starx: I'm 100% positive it works, try it. Tell me, why wouldn't it? (and OP's problem here was the redirect before setting session data, nothing more)

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't that be:

```
function langpref($lang){       
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->session->set_userdata('cur_lang', 'xxx');

    redirect(ABSOLUTE_PATH, 'location');
}
```

And in your view:

```
<?php echo $this->session->userdata("cur_lang"); ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

session is global variable. if you want to use it in class or function. you need to access it by passing session variable as function argument. or you need to use global command. such as;

```
class XXX{
   public function processSession($_SESSION){
      return $_SESSION['xx'];
   }
}
```

or you could use global directive

```
class XXX{
   public function processSession(){
      global $_SESSION;
      return $_SESSION['xx'];
   }
}
```

other way is starting session in function

```
class XXX{
   public function processSession(){
      session_start();
      $_SESSION['xx'] = 'aaaa';
      return $_SESSION['xx'];
   }
}
```

other way, you cannot access session variable in function or class function

Comment: He is asking about session handling using codeigniter framework!